# How To Copy files in Directory to another Directory using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have lots of Directories Like Tmp/a-1,a-2...till a-1000.
Each TMP Directory Contains file called log.
Hence I Have to go inside every directory and change the file named log to log_orig. 
How to do this via script?

Answer (score 1):

`find -name log -type f -exec mv {} {}_orig \;` will do (as long you don't have `log` files in other directories that you don't want to touch)

Comment: You might want to add -type f to prevent renaming directories.